# 3D Molecular Printers

Tags: print-material

Are there commercially available molecular 3D printers that can create catalytic structures like Zeolites, if not are there any research efforts underway in such field?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is an interesting question, but it is potentially quite broad in its scope. If you can provide a bit more detail about why this is hard, or the nearest technology you know, that would make for a better question (and better questions get more visibility, and more good answers)

Comment: This is probably a bit out of most peoples knowledge here. Very high level academia. That said this is all I find http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/health/a14528/the-chemistry-3d-printer-can-craft-rare-medicinal-molecules-from-scratch/

Comment: Thank you for the welcome not Sean, I was looking at a powder bed technology that is currently used for parts manufacture not in molecular synthesis. but I think the link provided by StarWind is closer to what I had in mind -Thanks StarWind

Comment: I'm leaving this open despite it becoming outdated. I think that the content could be useful and could become a great Community Wiki as this field (molecular printing) develops over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The link I mentioned](http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/health/a14528/the-chemistry-3d-printer-can-craft-rare-medicinal-molecules-from-scratch/) from popular mechanics is the state of molecular 3d printing. So yes the printer does exist and can do some really impressive things. However as the article states it is limited to what it can create right now. The technology sounds really interesting. However it might be a bit out of our knowledge as it doesn't seem to be widely available passed the scientific academia world.

[This link here](https://www.sculpteo.com/blog/2015/10/28/3d-printing-for-the-chemical-industry/) talks about reactionware for Chemical Syntheses as well as a TED talk about it

Comment: This sounds like the first steps to a Star Trek style replicator.  Still a long way to go obviously, but I never realized we were even this far along.